# CSS for changing color of div containing the href

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of the `div` containing the `href`. I'm trying to do this with `a:target` & `a:visited` property. This doesn't seem to work. I'm obviously not targetting the right thing.

I have the below `nav` structure.

```
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <a href="#" ><div></div></a>
        <a href="#"  id="p1" class="current"><div>OPTION - 1</div></a>
        <a href="#" id="p2"><div>OPTION - 2</div></a>
        <a href="#" id="p3"><div>OPTION - 3</div></a>
        <a href="#" id="p4"><div>OPTOIN - 4</div></a>
        <a href="#" id="p5"><div>OPTION - 5</div></a>       
    </nav>
```

Below is the CSS relevant to the above

```
#main-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px; /* changed */
    position: fixed;
    background: #222;
    text-align: center; 
}

#main-nav a {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    text-align: left;
    max-height: 100px;
}


#main-nav a:hover, #main-nav a.current {
    background: #3c3c3c; 
}

#main-nav a:target {
    background: yellow; 
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve this please?

**UPDATED**

```
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <a href="#p0" ><div></div></a>
            <a href="#p1"  id="p1" class="current"><div>&nbsp DASHBOARD</div></a>
            <a href="#p2" id="p2"><div>OPTION - 1</div></a>
            <a href="#p3" id="p3"><div>OPTION - 2</div></a>
            <a href="#p4" id="p4"><div>OPTION - 3</div></a>
            <a href="#p5" id="p5"><div>OPTION - 4</div></a>     
        </nav>

:target div {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Why `a:target` and not `a:active`?

Comment: I'd like to change the color of the div. Sorry I should have mentioned that

Comment: What do you mean by "a clicked `href`"? Do you mean a link that the user has already visited or changing the background color of the parent element on some `mousedown` event?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question asking about the div

Comment: Do you mean https://jsfiddle.net/3201wzcs/ like that?

Comment: Thank you you Pangloss. Not exactly that, but it helps me for further stuff I plan to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```css
:target div {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
    <a href="#p1"  id="p1" class="current"><div>OPTION - 1</div></a>
    <a href="#p2" id="p2"><div>OPTION - 2</div></a>
    <a href="#p3" id="p3"><div>OPTION - 3</div></a>
    <a href="#p4" id="p4"><div>OPTOIN - 4</div></a>
    <a href="#p5" id="p5"><div>OPTION - 5</div></a>       
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you Maak. The `nav` is a floating sidebar. When it goes out of view, the highlight goes away. When the sidebar floats back in the next time, I'd like the color to remain. Is this possible?

Comment: I just updated my post. I hope that works for you now.

Comment: Thank you Maak. Nope it isn't :(

Comment: I updated the question with how it looks now. Same as your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Looking at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj83kong/) isn't this the behaviour you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107439/discussion-between-usert4jju7-and-maak).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to remove the div's since they are overwriting the markup you define on a:visited and a:hover. 
So if you are only changing the background color, since setting the background color of the div's parent 'a' will cover the background of the div.

I assumed you wanted to highlight the nav item with the .current class set.

```css
.current{
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
 <nav id="main-nav">
   <a href="#" id="p0"></a>
   <a href="#" id="p1" class="current">&nbsp; DASHBOARD</a>
   <a href="#" id="p2">OPTION - 1</a>
   <a href="#" id="p3">OPTION - 2</a>
   <a href="#" id="p4">OPTION - 3</a>
   <a href="#" id="p5">OPTION - 4</a>
   </ul>
</nav>
```